# Using Enum to apply Consumer

Tags: java

I have a utility called `ZipFileCombiner` that combines zip archives into a single archive.  Part of the implementation is using an `Enum` called `CollisionStrategy` to deal with entry collisions.  It's a nested `Enum`. It seems kind of ugly to me.  It feels like embedding that much code within the `Enum` seems wrong. I could create yet another inner class (or outer) to hold it, but that seems wrong as well since logic is tightly coupled to the idea of a strategy.  I'm looking for suggestions as well as a general peer review.

Full code [here in GitHub](https://github.com/MadConan/utility/blob/master/src/main/java/net/conan/file/ZipFileCombiner.java).  *(`IOUtil` is also in that project.)*

#### Relevant pieces:

#### `CollisionStrategy`

```
public enum CollisionStrategy {
    FAIL((bean, combiner) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Collision detected. Entry " + bean.entry() +
              " exists.  Current source: " + bean.source());
    }),
    USE_FIRST((bean, combiner) -> {}),
    RENAME_AND_ADD((bean, combiner) -> {
        if(bean.entry().isDirectory()){
            return;
        }

        String[] sourceNameParts = bean.source().getName().split("/");
        String sourceName = sourceNameParts[sourceNameParts.length-1];
        String[] entryNameParts = bean.entry().getName().split("/");
        String entryName = entryNameParts[entryNameParts.length-1];
        entryNameParts[entryNameParts.length-1] = sourceName + entryName;
        String newEntryName = Arrays.asList(entryNameParts).stream().collect(Collectors.joining("/"));

        // Have to manually "clone" the entry.  This sucks.
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(newEntryName);
        entry.setTime(bean.entry().getTime());
        entry.setComment(bean.entry().getComment());
        entry.setCompressedSize(bean.entry().getCompressedSize());
        entry.setCrc(bean.entry().getCrc());
        entry.setCreationTime(bean.entry().getCreationTime());
        entry.setMethod(bean.entry().getMethod());
        entry.setExtra(bean.entry().getExtra());
        entry.setLastAccessTime(bean.entry().getLastAccessTime());
        entry.setLastModifiedTime(bean.entry().getLastModifiedTime());
        try (InputStream in = bean.source().getInputStream(bean.entry())){
            combiner.copyEntryFromSourceToTarget(in,entry,bean.zipOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    });

    BiConsumer<CombinerBean,ZipFileCombiner> biConsumer;

    CollisionStrategy(BiConsumer<CombinerBean,ZipFileCombiner> consumer){
        biConsumer = consumer;
    }

    void apply(CombinerBean bean, ZipFileCombiner combiner){
        biConsumer.accept(bean,combiner);
    }
}
```

#### `CombinerBean`

```
/*
CombinerBean is used in the CollisionStrategy.  It only serves to clean up code such that long arg lists
aren't necessary.
 */
private static class CombinerBean{
    private final ZipEntry e;
    private final ZipFile src;
    private final ZipOutputStream out;

    public CombinerBean(ZipOutputStream zo, ZipEntry ze, ZipFile source){
        e = ze; src = source; out = zo;
    }

    public ZipEntry entry(){ return e; }
    public ZipFile  source(){ return src; }
    public ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream(){ return out; }
}
```

#### Method `addEntryContent` that refers to the strategy

```
private void addEntryContent(final ZipOutputStream out, final ZipFile source, final ZipEntry entry, final Set<String> entryNames) throws IOException {
    if(!entryNames.add(entry.getName())){
        // Assuming duplicate directory entries across archives are OK, so skip if directory
        if(!entry.isDirectory()) {
            LOGGER.warning(entry.getName() + " has already been added. Applying strategy: " + strategy);
            strategy.apply(new CombinerBean(out, entry, source), this);
        }
    }else {
        try (InputStream in = source.getInputStream(entry)) {
            copyEntryFromSourceToTarget(in, entry, out);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Method `copyEntryFromSourceToTarget` which is called by the strategy

```
private void copyEntryFromSourceToTarget(final InputStream in, final ZipEntry targetEntry, final ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.putNextEntry(targetEntry);
    IOUtil.readWrite(in, out);
    out.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but I usually keep enum's in all capital letters or some other way to easily pick out.

Comment: An alternative to wrapping a lambda is to make the `enum CollisionStrategy  implements BiConsumer<CombinerBean,ZipFileCombiner>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's best practices to let statements like `if, for,` ... be followed by a space to disinguish them from method invocations.
- #### CollisionStrategy

  I'd use:

  ```
  String.format("Collision detected. Entry %s exists. Current source: %s",
      bean.entry(), bean.source());
  ```

  instead of string concatenation:

  ```
  "Collision detected. Entry " + bean.entry() +
      " exists.  Current source: " + bean.source()
  ```

  The same applies to `addEntryContent().`
- #### CombinerBean

  Java best practices is "one statement per line" since your code is a lot more read (possibly by others, too) than it is written.
- #### addEntryContent() and copyEntryFromSourceToTarget()

  You break lines at ~104 in `CollisionStrategy` but you don`t do it in these methods. That's not consistent style.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I agree with your points in general, but I don't apply blanket rules to my code.  If a certain style for a block of code seems easier to read, even if it breaks conventions, then use it.  I understand it's a subjective call, so maybe others don't feel the same.

Comment: @MadConan What are you referring to in detail?

Comment: `CombinerBean`, one statement per line.  For the simplistic, one-line-code-blocks in a small inner class, I personally prefer seeing it all together at a glance as opposed to scrolling back and forth.

Comment: The `String.format` suggestion is a good one, though.  I need to start using that more.  Old habits die hard :)

Comment: @MadConan With 8 more lines you have to scroll? Are you developing on a smartphone in landscape view? :-)

Comment: Moving my eyes up and down is too hard. ;)